# Does V8 Ignition execute highly optimized machine code that is produced by Turbofan?

Tags: javascript, v8

I'm looking into description what V8 Ignition and Turbofan do, I can see that Ignition generates bytecode from AST and also executes it. Ignition sends some profiling data to Turbofan so Turbofan can optimize the code, it creates machine code out of it. Does Turbofan send machine code back to Ignition for execution?

Thank you and correct me pls if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Turbofan send machine code back to Ignition for execution?

No.

Ignition is the interpreter. It consists of two parts: the part that creates bytecode, and the part that executes/interprets that bytecode.

When executing bytecode, type information is collected on the side. When a function is selected for optimization, Turbofan consumes this collected information in order to produce optimized code. For a dynamic language like JavaScript, that's a large part of what "optimization" means.

Optimized machine code produced by Turbofan is executed directly -- that's what "machine code" means. (Ignition is not involved at all.)